# How to change twentytwelve child theme site title separator

Tags: themes, wp-title

I am using a child theme with WordPress twentytwelve.

I'm confused as to what function I can use in the child theme's functions.php to just change the site title separator, from its default vertical slash | to a hyphen -

Comment: Please post relevant code (either from `functions.php` or else from `header.php`), and we can help you. (Hint: look for the call to `wp_title()` in `header.php`.)

Comment: I know the title could be defined in the `header.php` file as `<?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?>` but I din't want to touch the existing header.php, but do it in a child theme's functions.php instead

Answer (score 2):

From this comment:

> I know the title could be defined in the header.php file as  but I din't want to touch the existing header.php, but do it in a child theme's functions.php instead

But Twenty Twelve isn't modifying the separator in its `wp_title` filter callback; rather, it is defining it in its call to `wp_title()`, in `header.php`:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Note that the `wp_title` callback merely passes `$sep` along, without modifying it:

```
function twentytwelve_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentytwelve' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentytwelve_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

You have two choices:

1. Replace `header.php` via Child Theme, and call:

   ```
   <title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
   ```
2. Remove Twenty Twelve's filter callback, and replace it with your own:

   ```
   function wpse87673_filter_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
       // Your callback code goes here
   }
   add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse87673_filter_wp_title', 11, 2 );
   remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentytwelve_wp_title', 10, 2 );
   ```

I don't think there is a more simple way to filter `$sep` directly. It is defined by the `wp_title()` function call parameter.

Comment: Your suggestion No. 1 is what I meant by defining the code in the header.php, but this wouldn't be as preferable as including code in a child theme's functions.php, but no callback code for that works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
 <?php

function johndoe999_filter_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
global $paged, $page;

$sep = ' - ';

$title = get_the_title();

if ( is_feed() ) {
return $title;
}

$title .= $sep;

$blogname = get_bloginfo('name');

// Add the site name.
$title .= $blogname;

// Add the site description for the home/front page.
$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
$title = "$blogname - $site_description";
}

// Add a page number if necessary.
if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) {
$title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentytwelve' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
}

return $title;
}


add_filter( 'wp_title', 'johndoe999_filter_wp_title', 10, 2 );

function johndoe999_remove_title () {
remove_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentytwelve_wp_title', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'johndoe999_remove_title' );


?>
```